# Short circuit evaluation In javascript

Tags: javascript, optimization, functional-programming, expression, conditional-statements

I am in a need to implement short circuit evaluation logic in my code. And I read some articles http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation, http://www.grauw.nl/blog/entry/510 to understand about it . But they haven't covered in detail and I tried up some examples.

Ex:

```
function a() {return true;}

function b() {return false;}

function c() {return true;}
```

Expression

Case 1) `a() && b() && c();`

Case 2) `a() || b() && c();`

Case 3) `a() && c() || b();`

Case 1:

`c()` will not be executed.

Case 2:

`b()` and `c()` will not be executed

Case 3:

`b()` will not be executed.

Where should we learn about this short-circuit evaluation?

Comment: Hi, please kindly look at my small blog about short circuiting and I hope it could help a little: http://js-guru.blogspot.com/2015/08/javascript-short-circuiting.html

Answer (score 4):

> Where should we learn about this short-circuit evaluation?

[The specification](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.11) is handy, as is [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).

But the short version is:

- The left-hand operand to `&&` or `||` is always evaluated, giving us the *left-hand value*.
- With `&&`, if the *left-hand value* is falsey, the right-hand operand is not evaluated; the expression's value is the left-hand value.
- With `||`, if the *left-hand value* is truthy, the right-hand operand is not evaluated; the expression's value is the left-hand value.
- Otherwise, the right-hand operand is evaluated and the expression's result is its value.

"Falsey" values are any value that coerces to `false` when used as a boolean. Those are `0`, `""`, `NaN`, `undefined`, `null`, and of course, `false`.

"Truthy" values are any values that aren't falsey.

More on my blog: [*JavaScript's Curiously-Powerful OR Operator (`||`)*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html). *(I keep meaning to do the `&&` version of that...)*

Comment: @t-j-crowder: Thanks for the info. Any idea why the left-hand operand is always evaluated?  Say, you could have `call() || true`, and you'd know the result is going to be true, so why bother making the call?  Basically, I'm just nervous that I can rely on this.

Comment: @rjcarr: The left-hand operand is always evaluated because that's how the operator is defined. And that definition makes sense: You have to start somewhere (remember, you don't know that `true` in your example is `true` until you evaluate it), and in our mathematics, most operations proceed left-to-right. Yes, you can absolutely know that `call() || true` will call `call` and then either return its result (if it's truthy) or `true` (if `call`'s result was falsey).